# Simple HTML Dom Parser - Skip elements with certain ID

Tags: dom, simple-html-dom

I am using Simple HTML Dom Parser to query Google for a specific keyword and then loop through the content. However, I do not want to query ads or the newsbox. Its easy to exclude ads since the list elements have a different class but the newsbox li element has the same class but an additional id.

**Result li element**

```
<li class="g">...</li>
```

**Newsbox li element**

```
<li class="g" id="newsbox">...</li>
```

How can I exclude li elements with the ID newsbox?

I had a read around here and this is the closest I came as per suggestion of one other guy but it didn't work:

```
$query = file_get_html('https://google.com/search?q=test');    
$li_elements = $query->find('li[class=g id!=newsbox]');
```

Any other ideas or someone that has solved this before?

## UPDATE

I am still working on this and I pretty much came to a dead end. This is my latest code:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=football');

// Find all article blocks
foreach($html->find('#res h3.r') as $article) {
    $item['title']     = $article->plaintext;
    $item['intro']    = $article->find('a', 0)->href;
    $articles[] = $item;
}

print_r($articles);
```

**And this is the printed array**

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => BBC Sport - Football
        [intro] => /url?q=http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/football/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CBQQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNGHTFqXJoRjHKBSCdKFiW_BX6eGDw
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => News for football
        [intro] => /search?q=football&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;prmd=ivnsl&amp;source=univ&amp;tbm=nws&amp;tbo=u&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CB8QqAI
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => Football Games, Results, Scores, Transfers, News | Sky Sports
        [intro] => /url?q=http://www1.skysports.com/football/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CCgQFjAE&amp;usg=AFQjCNE4VP4WAHIYJAoPIBJoUx1pC-1jBA
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [title] => Local business results for football near London NW5
        [intro] => https://maps.google.co.uk/maps?um=1&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;fb=1&amp;gl=uk&amp;q=football&amp;hq=football&amp;hnear=0x48761a535791ef6f:0x493f677c231558c8,London+NW5&amp;sa=X&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CC4QtQM
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [title] => Football news, match reports and fixtures | Football | The Guardian
        [intro] => /url?q=http://www.theguardian.com/football&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CE4QFjAM&amp;usg=AFQjCNHPhgIljb53cFPRHlb1vCa1fmWJag
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [title] => NewsNow: Football News | Breaking News &amp; Search 24/7
        [intro] => /url?q=http://www.newsnow.co.uk/h/Sport/Football&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CFQQFjAN&amp;usg=AFQjCNEmmlrEayvHdebKTfPykGhHxRioLA
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [title] => Football365 - Football News, Views, Gossip and much more...
        [intro] => /url?q=http://www.football365.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CFoQFjAO&amp;usg=AFQjCNFKIP3xgtxw9DhNtOhVfpT4pbpLPw
    )

[7] => Array
    (
        [title] => Football - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia
        [intro] => /url?q=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Football&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CGAQFjAP&amp;usg=AFQjCNF2Fk8WH4rzEvWzmYIEUycZnjvjpg
    )

[8] => Array
    (
        [title] => Football in London - Things To Do - visitlondon.com
        [intro] => /url?q=http://www.visitlondon.com/things-to-do/whats-on/sport/football&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CGYQFjAQ&amp;usg=AFQjCNEdSNJc-mlVpaWEY9yPjcoDSaDLIw
    )

[9] => Array
    (
        [title] => London Football Leagues - 5-a-side - 7-a-side - 11-a-side - Midweek ...
        [intro] => /url?q=http://www.londonfootball.co.uk/&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CHMQFjAR&amp;usg=AFQjCNGnZtZQxUmUYQtDF0Tj5nJRnR2Yig
    )

[10] => Array
    (
        [title] => Football Tickets and Event Details | Ticketmaster UK Sport
        [intro] => /url?q=http://www.ticketmaster.co.uk/browse/football-catid-11/sport-rid-10004&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=NkblU-s8h6nQBcCJgOAI&amp;ved=0CHkQFjAS&amp;usg=AFQjCNFwTfpq-klboIEf0EbhlMQWvzHeKQ
    )
```

)

I don't understand why the second result, `array[1][title]`, is stored in the array since as per this line `$html->find('#res h3.r') as $article` it shouldn't. Its neither wrapped within a div with id #res nor within a h3 tag.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Simple HTML Dom Parser doesnt support such flexibility, however a workarround can be found...

You can first remove the unwanted block, then retrieve the right one:

1. `$query->find('li#newsbox', 0)->outertext = '';`
2. `$li_elements = $query->find('li.g');`

### Edit:

Here's an example code showing how it works:

```
$input =  <<<_DATA_
<div class="g" id="newsbox">Bad node</div>
<div class="g">Usefull node</div>
_DATA_;

// Create a DOM object
$html = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$html->load($input);

// Remove the bad node
$html->find('div#newsbox', 0)->outertext = ''; // Comment this line to print the original html content

echo $html;
```

<kbd>[Working code](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4muh-v6he)</kbd>

Comment: I just tried this but I get the error "Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in...." and it still queries all list elements. Any thoughts?

Comment: It should work, check teh demo I added... maybe the error comes from somewhere else...

Comment: Its not working for me. Please see my updated answer ... for some reason the "News section" is always scraped as well.

Answer (score 0):

simple_html_dom claims to support that so it appears to be a bug.

The proper css way to select that would be `li.g:not(#newsbox)` which is not supported by simple, but is supported by [this one](https://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/).

Answer (score 0):

How about this idea

```
// Remove HTML tags
$elements_remove = array('#newsbox','header','footer','script','css');
foreach($elements_remove as $e) {
    foreach($html->find($e) as $item) {
        $item->innertext = '';
    }
}
```

That works for me. I added in some HTML elements as well in the exclusion array.